# Is it possible and is it good practice to expose DynamoDb Optimistic Locking Version to clients to prevent race conditions at a higher level?

Tags: transactions, amazon-dynamodb, optimistic-locking

Here's the general race condition problem

1. Resource is created with a list
2. ServiceA and ServiceB wants to add something to the list within Resource

   1. ServiceA gets Resource (list=[])
   2. ServiceB gets Resource (list=[])
   3. ServiceA updates Resource (list=[A]) and succeeds
   4. ServiceB updates Resource (list=[B]) and succeeds

Expected: Resource(list=[A,B]) or an Exception

Actual: Resource(list=[B])
And even worse, this is a silent failure

With [DynamoDB's Optimistic Locking with Version Number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html), we can solve this and the scenario looks like this.

1. Resource is created with a list (and version=1)
2. ServiceA and ServiceB wants to add something to the list within Resource

   1. ServiceA gets Resource (list=[], version=1)
   2. ServiceB gets Resource (list=[], version=1)
   3. ServiceA updates Resource (list=[A], version=1) and succeeds (version becomes 2)
   4. ServiceB updates Resource (list=[B], version=1) and fails because version is behind

So ServiceB is notified of the failure and can decide to retry the attempt by refetching the Resource (with version=2 and list=[A]) and updating the Resource (list=[A,B], version=2).

DynamoDB manages the version for you. It sets the version to 1 when the resource is created, auto-increments it on every update, and throws an exception if the versions don't match.

My question is, is it ok to expose that version to the clients during their Get-Requests (assuming the client isn't our code but some other service that's owned by our org) and allow them to provide it during their Update-Requests?

- First part of that question is, is this technically possible?
- Second part of that question is, is this good practice? (ie. are there any issues with doing this even if we technically can?)

Comment: "DynamoDB manages the version for you" - what gives you that impression? There are SDKs that have this concept built into them, but it just uses conditions in DynamoDB.

Comment: "save-...DynamoDBMapper assigns an initial version number of 1. If you retrieve an item, update one or more of its properties, and attempt to save the changes, the save operation succeeds only if the version number on the client side and the server side match. The DynamoDBMapper increments the version number automatically."

Comment: That's not really DynamoDB that is doing this for you, it's the DynamoDBMapper. What is being done is a field is added to the data to hold the "version" and a "save" operation is using a condition that says "version" must still be what it was before, and as a part of the save operation it sets the value one higher. The version is **NOT** native to DynamoDB.

Comment: What are you suggesting then--that yes, it's fine to expose the version to clients and have them return it on subsequent request?

Comment: Sure, but there are alternatives. I'll write an answer, now that I understand your scenario better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, DynamoDB doesn't really have the concept of versioning of a record. That concept is introduced by some libraries that add a version field and take advantage of [Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) on the `PutItem` call. So, in that regard, you aren't really exposing a DynamoDB value, you're exposing a value that you have chosen to add to your data (albeit via an SDK).

Second, there very well may be a better approach to this. Consider using [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) and take advantage of some of the more advanced [UpdateExpressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression), specifically the `ADD` operation.

> If the existing data type is a set and if Value is also a set, then Value is added to the existing set. For example, if the attribute value is the set [1,2], and the ADD action specified [3], then the final attribute value is [1,2,3]. An error occurs if an ADD action is specified for a set attribute and the attribute type specified does not match the existing set type.

This can allow you to do partial updates and not be concerned about multiple requests changing the same data. It has its limits, but in your exact scenario I believe this would work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I don't think the ADD operation will help for all my use cases, but I think you still answered my concerns about the @ DynamoDBVersionAttribute. Namely, it's nothing special within DynamoDB, but just another value that happens to be managed by middleware libraries